# Typing only non null fields?

Tags: c#

```
string[] lines = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text };
Random RandString = new Random();
string text = lines[RandString.Next(0, lines.Length)];
SendKeys.SendWait(text);
```

How can I select textBox's with text inside of them? I was trying to sort the data `string[] lines` into a new `string[] hasText`  but I'm unsure how to go about checking if the textBox has text inside of it.

If the textBox field is null it will still process through RandString and SendKeys will try to type it out.  How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array with LINQ:

```
string[] hasText = lines.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the IsNullOrEmpty ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx))

```
TextBox[] textboxes = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6};

List<string> lines = new List<string>();

foreach(Textbox tb in textboxes)
{
    if (!tb.text.IsNullOrEmpty()
    {
        lines.Add(tb);
    }
}

Random RandString = new Random();
string text = lines[RandString.Next(0, lines.Length)];
SendKeys.SendWait(text);
```

Note: I haven't compiled it